# How to sort a typed array in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I built a custom class which holds an "internal" array and offers some useful methods.

```
class ArrayList<T> {
  private var array : Array<T>

  public init() {
    array = Array<T>()
  }

  public func add(element : T) {
    array.append(element)
  }

  public func size() -> Int {
    return array.count
  }

  ...
}
```

Ok, that works fine for me so far.
But now I also want to have a method to sort the array. What I already have is the following:

```
public func sort(comparator : ?) {
  array = array.sort(comparator)
}
```

**The question mark stands for the parameter type and that is my problem:** Which type must the parameter have? I read something about @noescape<*,*> but I can't get it to work!
I'm using Swift 2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is the use the standard closure

```
public func sort(comparator : (T, T) -> Bool) {
   array.sortInPlace(comparator)
}
```

and constrain the generic type to the `Comparable` protocol

```
class ArrayList<T : Comparable>
```

Then you can use this code

```
let arrayList = ArrayList<Int>()
arrayList.add(5)
arrayList.add(12)
arrayList.add(10)
arrayList.add(2)

arrayList.sort { $0 < $1 }

print(arrayList.array) // [2, 5, 10, 12]
```

Comment: Why would you restrict T to Comparable, you're disallowing non-comparable elements just because they can't be sorted with `<` and`>`?

If anything, you could add an extension that only applies when T is comparable that offers a default sort function.

Comment: I know I just wanted to answer the question quite simply and avoid the *Binary Operator < cannot be applied to...* error message.

Comment: this will work fine without the restriction as well as long as T is Comparable. And if it isn't you shouldn't expect to be able to compare it using `<` and you can still compare it some other way.